# Enabling Deep Links for App Content in Smartface

Tags: smartface.io

How to Enabling Deep Links for App Content in Smartface App Studio?

Desc: Having a webpage or mail which will contains the link. When user clicks on that link in mobile web browser or any mailing app, my app should open and an page need to load. 
Can any one please suggest how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this easily with a 3rd party solution like Branch. Here is a link for deep linking api:

https://dev.branch.io/